# Alternar as cores de uma coluna usando a biblioteca de java - apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, style

Estou utilizando java com a biblioteca apache poi para criar uma planilha excel. 

Preciso ficar alternando as cores, da 1ª coluna (que é de departamento), entre amarelo e azul, quando os dados forem diferentes também.Ex.:


 Dep = 1 - Cor = amarelo

 Dep = 1 - Cor = amarelo

 Dep = 2 - Cor = azul

 Dep = 2 - Cor = azul

 Dep = 3 - Cor = amarelo 

(e assim por diante)

Toda vez que alterar um departamento eu preciso alterar a cor, porém com o algoritmo que eu pensei ou tenho o resultado todo em amarelo ou todo em azul. Não estou conseguindo pensar em outro algoritmo.

```
        HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        HSSFPalette palette = workbook.getCustomPalette();
        int mudou = 0;

        for (int i=0; i <teste.length; i++) 
        {
            row = sheet.createRow(i+5);

            if (mudou == 0 )
            {                   

                palette.setColorAtIndex(palette.getColor(36).getIndex(), (byte) 255, (byte) 255 , (byte) 204 ); //amarelo
                style.setFillForegroundColor(palette.getColor(36).getIndex());
                style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

                if (i>0 && !teste[i].getDepto().equals(teste[i-1].getDepto()) )
                {
                    mudou = 1;
                }
            }
            if (mudou == 1)
            {
                palette.setColorAtIndex(palette.getColor(8).getIndex(), (byte) 204, (byte) 255, (byte) 255); //azul
                style.setFillForegroundColor(palette.getColor(8).getIndex());
                style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

                if(i+1<teste.length && !teste[i].getDepto().equals(teste[i+1].getDepto()) )
                {
                    mudou = 0;
                }
            }           

            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(teste[i].getDepto());
            row.getCell(0).setCellStyle(style);

            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(teste[i].getSigla());
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(teste[i].getCiclo());
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue(teste[i].getState());
            row.createCell(4).setCellValue(teste[i].getDataEntradaEstado());
            row.createCell(5).setCellValue("");
            row.createCell(6).setCellValue(teste[i].getId());
        }
```

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma bem simples é criar um método para isso:

```
private static void estilizarCor(CellStyle estilo, Integer indiceColuna) {
  IndexedColors[] cores = new IndexedColors[]{
    IndexedColors.AQUA, IndexedColors.RED
  };

  short indiceCor = 0;

  for (Integer indice = cores.length - 1; indice >= 0; indice--) {
    if (indice % indiceColuna == 0) {
      indiceCor = cores[indice].getIndex();
      break;
    }
  }

  estilo.setFillForegroundColor(indiceCor);
  estilo.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
}
```

E utilizar no seu código da seguinte forma:

```
estilizarCor(style, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

consegui galera... Deve ter algum jeito bem mais prático, mas vou postar aqui o que eu fiz para quem precisar:

```
        int mudou = 0;
        String depPassado = "";

        for (int i=0; i <teste.length; i++) 
        {
            row = sheet.createRow(i+5);

            //TODO alternando a cor entre os Deps
            if (i == 0)
            {
                depPassado = teste[i].getDepto();

                HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
                HSSFPalette palette = workbook.getCustomPalette();

                palette.setColorAtIndex(palette.getColor(36).getIndex(), (byte) 255, (byte) 255 , (byte) 204 ); //amarelo
                style.setFillForegroundColor(palette.getColor(36).getIndex());
                style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

                row.createCell(0).setCellStyle(style);
            }
            else if (depPassado.equals(teste[i].getDepto()))
            {
                if (mudou == 0)
                {
                    HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
                    HSSFPalette palette = workbook.getCustomPalette();

                    palette.setColorAtIndex(palette.getColor(36).getIndex(), (byte) 255, (byte) 255 , (byte) 204 ); //amarelo
                    style.setFillForegroundColor(palette.getColor(36).getIndex());
                    style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

                    row.createCell(0).setCellStyle(style);
                }

                else 
                {
                    HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
                    HSSFPalette palette = workbook.getCustomPalette();

                    palette.setColorAtIndex(palette.getColor(8).getIndex(), (byte) 204, (byte) 255, (byte) 255); //azul
                    style.setFillForegroundColor(palette.getColor(8).getIndex());
                    style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

                    row.createCell(0).setCellStyle(style);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (mudou == 0) mudou = 1;
                else mudou = 0;
                depPassado = teste[i].getDepto();

                if (mudou == 0)
                {
                    HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
                    HSSFPalette palette = workbook.getCustomPalette();

                    palette.setColorAtIndex(palette.getColor(36).getIndex(), (byte) 255, (byte) 255 , (byte) 204 ); //amarelo
                    style.setFillForegroundColor(palette.getColor(36).getIndex());
                    style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

                    row.createCell(0).setCellStyle(style);
                }

                else 
                {
                    HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
                    HSSFPalette palette = workbook.getCustomPalette();

                    palette.setColorAtIndex(palette.getColor(8).getIndex(), (byte) 204, (byte) 255, (byte) 255); //azul
                    style.setFillForegroundColor(palette.getColor(8).getIndex());
                    style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

                    row.createCell(0).setCellStyle(style);
                }

            }
```